# Vertically align a block and an image side by side

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, columns, block

I want to set a block and an image side by side, and vertically align them either from the top or in the middle. But I realize that with neither `\begin{columns}[T]` nor `\begin{columns}[c]` works perfectly. It seems that there is a margin on top of the block.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{}
        lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala
      \end{block}
    \end{column}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{screenshot3.png}
    \end{column}%
  \end{columns}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: It is better now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `[c]` option for the vertical alignment of the columns, but it doesn't seem to work with the `block` environment, so I had to use `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}
  \begin{columns}[c]
    \begin{column}[c]{.48\textwidth}
 \begin{block}{\rlap{Portrait of Simonetta Vespucci}}
        lala\dotfill \\ lala\dotfill \\ lala\dotfill \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala \\ lala\dotfill \\ lala\dotfill \\ lala\dotfill
 \end{block}
    \end{column}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{column}[c]{.48\textwidth}
   \raisebox{-1.32\height}[0pt]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Piero_di_Cosimo_3bis}}}
    \end{column}%
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But how did you calculate '-1.32'?

Comment: Just trial and error, since the block environment seems to inhibit any centring. The main point is to fool LaTeX, making it believe the image has a height of 0, thanks to the optional argument.